# Get the keys for duplicate values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, key

I have the following array:

```
$myarray = Array("2011-06-21", "2011-06-22", "2011-06-22", "2011-06-23", "2011-06-23", "2011-06-24", "2011-06-24", "2011-06-25", "2011-06-25", "2011-06-26");
var_dump($myarray);
```

Result:

```
Array (
    [0] => 2011-06-21
    [1] => 2011-06-22
    [2] => 2011-06-22
    [3] => 2011-06-23
    [4] => 2011-06-23
    [5] => 2011-06-24
    [6] => 2011-06-24
    [7] => 2011-06-25
    [8] => 2011-06-25
    [9] => 2011-06-26
)
```

1. Now how can I display the keys with duplicate values? Here the function should NOT return ([0],[9]) since there are no duplicates with the values.
2. How to find the keys for the same value, eg. for "2011-06-25" it should return [7],[8]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```php
function get_keys_for_duplicate_values($my_arr, $clean = false) {
    if ($clean) {
        return array_unique($my_arr);
    }

    $dups = $new_arr = array();
    foreach ($my_arr as $key => $val) {
      if (!isset($new_arr[$val])) {
         $new_arr[$val] = $key;
      } else {
        if (isset($dups[$val])) {
           $dups[$val][] = $key;
        } else {
           $dups[$val] = array($key);
           // Comment out the previous line, and uncomment the following line to
           // include the initial key in the dups array.
           // $dups[$val] = array($new_arr[$val], $key);
        }
      }
    }
    return $dups;
}
```

obviously the function name is a bit long;)

Now $dups will contain a multidimensional array keyed by the duplicate value, containing each key that was a duplicate, and if you send "true" as your second argument it will return the original array without the duplicate values.

Alternately you could pass the original array as a reference and it would adjust it accordingly while returning your duplicate array

Comment: you could shorten the code path when `$clean === true` by putting `if ($clean === true) { return array_unique($my_arr); }` at the top ;)

Comment: By the way, fastest method I've tested so far, handles 100 iterations of an 100,000+ element array in approx 0.04463 seconds per iteration!

Comment: Changed my testing methodology a bit and while still fastest, actual iteration time is closer to 0.1811 seconds; the array had (on average) 165,000 elements, 100,000 of which were unique.

Comment: Maybe this was not the intention of the function but this function returns non-duplicate values too. Just wanted to mention this. I did a `foreach ($dups as $k=>$v) { if( count($v) == 1) unset($dups[$k]); }` to fix this but I think this not very effective.

Comment: Oops, there was a logic problem, it should have been `if(!isset($new_arr[$val]))`, I fixed it and it should work as expected now

Comment: Maybe this is intentional, but this function doesn't return all the keys that have duplicate values. It returns only the keys after the first one found. I see how that could be intentional (you could consider only the later ones "duplicates"), but it was confusing to me. I expected it to return *all* keys that had values that other keys also had.

Comment: @goron That was the intention, but I definitely see how it would be useful to have either option, so I've updated with a comment to basically make this function act as you expected.

Comment: @Trey Thank you so much! you made my day.

Answer (score 19):

I'll answer the second question first. You want to use [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the "search_value" specified.

```
$keys = array_keys($array, "2011-06-29")
```

In the example below, `$duplicates` will contain the duplication values while `$result` will contain ones that are not duplicates. To get the keys, simply use `array_keys`.

```
<?php

$array = array(
  'a',
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd'
);

// Unique values
$unique = array_unique($array);

// Duplicates
$duplicates = array_diff_assoc($array, $unique);

// Unique values
$result = array_diff($unique, $duplicates);

// Get the unique keys
$unique_keys = array_keys($result);

// Get duplicate keys
$duplicate_keys = array_keys(array_intersect($array, $duplicates));
```

Result:

```
// $duplicates
Array
(
    [1] => a
)

// $result
Array
(
    [2] => b
    [3] => c
    [4] => d
)

// $unique_keys
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)

// $duplicate_keys
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
```

Comment: This will return values, not keys.

Comment: @cypher - You're right. I forgot to include `array_keys`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Also, interesting question would be if he wanted to print out all the duplicate keys - in your case `0` and `1` for `a`

Comment: @cypher - A simple `array_keys(array_intersect($array, $duplicates))` would do just that. :)

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I like the unique / diff approach. But OP asked not for the unique, but those keys that are not unique. So probably you should not only put that into comment but into your answer as well.

Comment: This is only really useful on small arrays -- the larger the array, the more that iterating over it several times and running these comparisons is going to hurt.  Really fast for small enough sets, though =)

Comment: In the instance that you would like to also know the number of "pairs" within the duplicates you could also use count(array_unique($duplicates)); so if you duplicates array was ("a","b","a","b") this would return 2

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem as question #1 from the OP. All I needed were the keys for duplicate values in my original array. Here's what I came up with:

```
$array = array('yellow', 'red', 'green', 'brown', 'red', 'brown');

$counts = array_count_values($array);
$filtered = array_filter($counts, function($value) {
    return $value != 1;
});
$result = array_keys(array_intersect($array, array_keys($filtered)));
```

And for the output:

```
print_r($result);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a code dude

```
   $your_array = array(0 => '2011-06-21', 1 => '2011-06-22', 2 => '2011-06-22', 3 => '2011-06-23', 4 =>
'2011-06-23', 5 => '2011-06-24', 6 => '2011-06-24', 7 => '2011-06-25', 8 => '2011-06-25', 9 
=> '2011-06-26', 10 => '2011-06-26', 11 => '2011-06-27', 12 => '2011-06-27', 13 => '2011-06-  
28', 14 => '2011-06-29', 15 => '2011-06-29', 16 => '2011-06-30', 17 => '2011-06-30', 18 => 
'2011-07-01', 19 => '2011-07-01', 20 => '2011-07-02', 21 => '2011-07-02', 22 => '2011-07-03', 
23 => '2011-07-03', 24 => '2011-07-04', 25 => '2011-07-04', 26 => '2011-07-05', 27 => '2011-
07-05', 28 => '2011-07-06', 29 => '2011-07-06', 30 => '2011-07-07', 31 => '2011-07-07');

$keys_of_duplicated = array();
$array_keys = array();

foreach($your_array as $key => $value) {
    //- get the keys of the actual value
    $array_keys = array_keys($your_array, $value);

    //- if there is more then one key collected we register it
    if(count($array_keys) > 1) {
        //- foreach key that have the same value we check if i'ts already registered
        foreach($array_keys as $key_registered) {
            //- if not registered we register it
            if(!in_array($key_registered,  $keys_of_duplicated)) {
                 $keys_of_duplicated[] = $key_registered;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($keys_of_duplicated);
```

$keys_of_duplicated is now the array that contains the keys of duplicated arrays ;) bye

Comment: In my testing, this times out (60 seconds) on a sufficiently large array (100,000 in my test).

Answer (score 1):

I really like Francois answer, here is something I came up with that preserves keys. I'll answer the first question first:

```
$array = array('2011-06-21', '2011-06-22', '2011-06-22');
/**
 * flip an array like array_flip but
 * preserving multiple keys per an array value
 * 
 * @param array $a
 * @return array
 */
function array_flip_multiple(array $a) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($a as $k=>$v)
        $result[$v][]=$k
        ;
    return $result;
}

$hash = array_flip_multiple($array);

// filter $hash based on your specs (2 or more)
$hash = array_filter($hash, function($items) {return count($items) > 1;});

// get all remaining keys
$keys = array_reduce($hash, 'array_merge', array());

var_dump($array, $hash, $keys);
```

output is:

```
# original array
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2011-06-21"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2011-06-22"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2011-06-22"
}

# hash (filtered)
array(1) {
  ["2011-06-22"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
  }
}

# the keys
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
```

So now the second question:

Just use the `$hash` to obtain the keys for the value:

`var_dump($hash['2011-06-22']);` returns the keys.

Benefit is, if you need to check multiple values, data is already stored in the hash and available for use.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getDuplicateValueKeys($my_arr, $clean = false) 
{
    if ($clean) {
        return array_unique($my_arr);
    }
    $dups = array();
    $new_arr = array();
    $dup_vals = array();

    foreach ($my_arr as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($new_arr[$value])) {
            $new_arr[$value] = $key;
        } else {
            array_push($dup_vals,$value);
        }
    }

    foreach ($my_arr as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($value, $dup_vals)) {
            if (!isset($dups[$value])) {
                $dups[$value]=array($key);
            }else{
                array_push($dups[$value],$key);
            }
        }
    }

    return $dups;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(0 => "1", 1 => "1", 2 => "2", 3 => "3");
$count = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  if(!isset($count[$value])) {
    $count[$value] = 0;
  }
  $count[$value]++;
}


$result = array_filter($count, function($value) {
  return $value > 1;
});

$result = array_keys($result);

var_dump($result);
```

Output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: This unexplained answer does not appear to meet the brief.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    '2011-06-21','2011-06-22','2011-06-22','2011-06-23',
    '2011-06-23','2011-06-24','2011-06-24','2011-06-25',
    '2011-06-25','2011-06-26','2011-06-26','2011-06-27',
    '2011-06-27','2011-06-28','2011-06-29','2011-06-29',
    '2011-06-30','2011-06-30','2011-07-01','2011-07-01',
    '2011-07-02','2011-07-02','2011-07-03','2011-07-03',
    '2011-07-04','2011-07-04','2011-07-05','2011-07-05',
    '2011-07-06','2011-07-06','2011-07-07','2011-07-07',
);

function getDupKeys(array $array, $return_first = true, $return_by_key = true) {
    $seen = array();
    $dups = array();

    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        $vk = $return_by_key ? $v : 0;
        if (!array_key_exists($v, $seen)) {
            $seen[$v] = $k;
            continue;
        }
        if ($return_first && !array_key_exists($v, $dups)) {
            $dups[$vk][] = $seen[$v];
        }
        $dups[$vk][] = $k;
    }
    return $return_by_key ? $dups : $dups[0];
}
```

If both optional parameters are true, it returns an array of arrays; the key of each child array will be the value which was not unique, and the values of the array will be all those keys which had that value.

If the first optional parameter is false, then only keys *after* the first instance of a non-unique value will be returned (i.e., for the given array, each value returns only one key, the second time it occurred, instead of the first).

If the second parameter is optional, then instead of returning an array of arrays, it returns a flat array containing all duplicate keys (exactly which keys it returns are dictated by the prior optional parameter).

Here's a <s>dump</s>print_r, cause it's prettier:

```
print_r(getDupKeys($array));

Array
(
    [2011-06-22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2011-06-23] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

    [2011-06-24] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
        )

    [2011-06-25] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
        )

    [2011-06-26] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 10
        )

    [2011-06-27] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 12
        )

    [2011-06-29] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 15
        )

    [2011-06-30] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 17
        )

    [2011-07-01] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => 19
        )

    [2011-07-02] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 21
        )

    [2011-07-03] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 23
        )

    [2011-07-04] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
            [1] => 25
        )

    [2011-07-05] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26
            [1] => 27
        )

    [2011-07-06] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28
            [1] => 29
        )

    [2011-07-07] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 31
        )

)
```

---

```
print_r(getDupKeys($array, false));

Array
(
    [2011-06-22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [2011-06-23] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [2011-06-24] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
        )

    [2011-06-25] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
        )

    [2011-06-26] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [2011-06-27] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
        )

    [2011-06-29] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
        )

    [2011-06-30] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17
        )

    [2011-07-01] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
        )

    [2011-07-02] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
        )

    [2011-07-03] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
        )

    [2011-07-04] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
        )

    [2011-07-05] => Array
        (
            [0] => 27
        )

    [2011-07-06] => Array
        (
            [0] => 29
        )

    [2011-07-07] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
        )

)
```

---

```
print_r(getDupKeys($array, true, false));

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 12
    [12] => 14
    [13] => 15
    [14] => 16
    [15] => 17
    [16] => 18
    [17] => 19
    [18] => 20
    [19] => 21
    [20] => 22
    [21] => 23
    [22] => 24
    [23] => 25
    [24] => 26
    [25] => 27
    [26] => 28
    [27] => 29
    [28] => 30
    [29] => 31
)
```

---

```
print_r(getDupKeys($array, false, false));

Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 12
    [6] => 15
    [7] => 17
    [8] => 19
    [9] => 21
    [10] => 23
    [11] => 25
    [12] => 27
    [13] => 29
    [14] => 31
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
$array = array(
  'a',
  'a',
  'b',
  'b',
  'b'
);
echo '<br/>Array: ';
print_r($array);
// Unique values
$unique = array_unique($array);
echo '<br/>Unique Values: ';
print_r($unique);
// Duplicates
$duplicates = array_diff_assoc($array, $unique);
echo '<br/>Duplicates: ';
print_r($duplicates);
// Get duplicate keys
$duplicate_values = array_values(array_intersect($array, $duplicates));
echo '<br/>duplicate values: ';
print_r($duplicate_values);
```

Output:

```
Array :Array ( [0] => a [1] => a [2] => b [3] => b [4] => b ) 
Unique Values :Array ( [0] => a [2] => b ) 
Duplicates :Array ( [1] => a [3] => b [4] => b ) 
Duplicate Values :Array ( [0] => a [1] => a [2] => b [3] => b [4] => b )
```

Comment: Probably not a good demonstration when every element in the input array is also found in the result array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution for question 1 that I have used to get duplicates in a one-dimensional array:

Taking for example this array:

```
$arr = ['a','b','c','d','a','a','b','c','c'];
```

I like to avoid loops if possible, so I used `array_map` to solve this problem:

```
/**
 * Find multiple occurrences in a one-dimensional array
 *
 * @param array $list List to find duplicates for.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function fetchDuplicates(array $list)
{
    return array_filter(
        array_map(
            function ($el) use ($list) {
                $keysOccur = array_keys($list, $el);
                if (count($keysOccur) > 1) {
                    return $keysOccur;
                }

                return null;
            },
            array_unique($list)
        )
    );

}//end fetchDuplicates()
```

The `array_map` function loops every unique element of the `$list` and uses the original `$list` to get the array keys of occurrences with `array_keys($list, $el)`. If the resulting occurrence count is more than 1, the index is returned of all the occurrences and replaces the original `$el` with the array of indices. Otherwise `null` is returned, which also replaces the `$el` in the unique variant of `$list`. Finally the resulting array is filtered for empty values (as is the case with `null` values). Resulting in the following array:

```
[
  [
    0,
    4,
    5,
  ],
  [
    1,
    6,
  ],
  [
    2,
    7,
    8,
  ],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a classic `foreach()` to unconditionally group&push a newly structured array with all values as keys and all keys as indexed elements in the group's subarray.

Then to filter out the dates that only have one element, call the native `array_key_last()` function to remove date entries where the highest index in the subarray is `0`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EjMoE))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($myarray as $k => $v) {
    $result[$v][] = $k;
}
var_export(array_filter($result, 'array_key_last'));
```

Output:

```
array (
  '2011-06-22' => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
  ),
  '2011-06-23' => 
  array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 4,
  ),
  '2011-06-24' => 
  array (
    0 => 5,
    1 => 6,
  ),
  '2011-06-25' => 
  array (
    0 => 7,
    1 => 8,
  ),
)
```

<sup>Like many other answers on this page, this technique will not be suitable for any data types that cannot become keys (such as iterable type data) or that lose data integrity when assigned as a key (such as float type data).</sup>