# Value with same name in Array

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I want to check is there a value with same name in array,
if there is a value with same name, how can i get it.
Let's say i have

```
    <?php
if (is_array(Yii::app()->session['cart_values']))
{
    foreach ( Yii::app()->session['cart_values'] as $value) {


?>
```

and what is next, again go through another array which contain $files name and check it if there is file with same name.

I try few solutions but not get it.

Thanks

Comment: hard to guess what is your problem here.

Comment: can be done using array_unique() and array_diff()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460993/get-the-keys-for-duplicate-values-in-an-array

Answer (score 1):

Try smething like this

```
<?php
if (is_array(Yii::app()->session['cart_values']))
{
    foreach ( Yii::app()->session['cart_values'] as $values) {
    // get the uniques (assuming that $values is an array)
    $uniques = array_unique($values);

     // get the common values on each arrays so you get the repeated values
     $union = array_diff($values, $uniques);
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.