# update my session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, yii

I have form on cart view, 
and after name, item cost, I have quantity text field,

```
<?php echo CHtml::textField('quantity', $value['quantity']); ?>
```

if i change quantity text field and click on submit (button named update cart), 
i want to change the default quantity number to new, updated number.

This is what I try, in my controller i put this,

```
if(isset($_POST['updateCart'])){
        $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];

        }else {
        $quantity=1;
        }

$sessionCart[] = array('product_id' => $_POST['documents'], 'document' => $productInfo->name, 'countriesIssued'=>$_POST['countriesIssued'], 'countriesIntended'=>$_POST['countriesIntended'], 'quantity'=>$quantity, 'price' => $legalisationPrice->FCO);
```

and after the form is submited the value is 1, not my new value that i entered.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your `if(isset($_POST['updateCart'])` is not working.Check in firebug that what is being post.

Comment: Have you checked that the process goes inside your `if`? Try to print $_POST.

Comment: You forgot the closing bracket for the condition `if(isset($_POST['updateCart'])**)**{`

Comment: @topher, sorry for that, my mistake i edited my post.

Comment: @lebugg, it looks something is wrong in my if statement, i'm going to find out what.Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value with same name in Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062859/value-with-same-name-in-array) - do not duplicate your own questions - ***NEVER EVER*** - instead edit the previous one to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Close the Opening Brace of if condition before else

Comment: Thanks Sudhanshu, i did that, this was mistake because i write it(not copy) and i forgot to close it :)

Comment: is your `$_POST['updateCart']` working?Did your check on Firebug?

Comment: Yes it's working, under, net, post section it shows the new value, but not on the form.

Comment: Check the session array also.If it contains the new value or not.