# Find all differences in arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');

$array2 = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'black');
```

I want to know the differences between them.

`array_diff()` can be used to tell me that black only appears in the second array

`array_unique()` will only show me the unique values / removes the duplicate values but does not tell me that `blue` was the value removed due to being unique.

Is there a function to tell me the duplicated value in the second array (`blue`)?

Comment: there is non, u need to write your own method for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460993/get-the-keys-for-duplicate-values-in-an-array

Comment: Do you want to know the keys of those values as well?

Answer (score 2):

There is none, but You can use the one I've written below:

```
<?php
// function
function dupes_in_array($array){
  if(!is_array($array)) return 0; // check, if $array is an array
  $arr = array_count_values($array);
  foreach($arr as $key => $val) { if($val > 1) $duplicates[] = $key; }
  return $duplicates;
}

// demonstration
$array = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'black', 'green');
$dupes = dupes_in_array($array);
echo "Duplicate values: ";
var_dump($dupes);

?>
```

Output:

```
Duplicate values: array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "blue" [1]=> string(5) "green" }
```

Note: output is "blue" and "green", because the input array has both of them as duplicates.

If `$val` is `>` `1`, then we've got duplicate.

Reference: [array_count_values](http://php.net/array_count_values)

Answer (score 2):

**Finding the duplicate items in an array**

```
$result = array_filter(array_count_values($array2), function ($val) {
    return $val > 1;
});

$duplicates = array_keys($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => blue
)
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/102839)

Answer (score 1):

If you will preserve the keys values, [array_diff_assoc](https://www.php.net/array_diff_assoc) will work :

```
php > $a1 = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'black');
php > $a2 = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');
php > var_dump(array_diff_assoc($a1,$a2));
array(2) {
  [4]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "black"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might as well throw in my solution to the mix:

```
<?php

    $r1 = ["red","blue","green","yellow"];
    $r2 = ["red","blue","green","yellow","blue","black"];

    $diff = array_diff($r2,$r1);
    $dupe = array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($r2), function ($val){
                        return $val > 1;}));

    var_dump(array_merge($diff,$dupe));

?>
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "black"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "blue"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the difference by comparing `$array2` against `array_unique($array2)` like this:

```
print_r(array_diff_assoc($array2, array_unique($array2)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [4] => blue
)
```

It's not the most efficient, but it has the advantage of knowing the index of the duplicates.