# Count distinct key-value pairs in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping, counting

I need to count the unique key-value pairs in an array of arrays (regardless of which row they come from).

Sample input:

```
$info = [
    ['car' => 'Audi', 'previous_car' => 'BMW'],
    ['car' => 'Audi', 'previous_car' => 'Seat'],
    ['car' => 'Audi', 'previous_car' => 'BMW'],
    ['car' => 'BMW',  'previous_car' => 'BMW'],
    ['car' => 'Ford', 'previous_car' => 'Seat'],
];
```

Desired output:

```
[
    'car' => [
        'Audi' => 3,
        'BMW' => 1,
        'Ford' => 1
    ],
    'previous_car' => [
        'BMW' => 3,
        'Seat' => 2
    ]
]
```

I tried to use `array_value_count()`, but I doesn't work well on multidimensional arrays.

Comment: this question will help you which is lalready asked here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460993/get-the-keys-for-duplicate-values-in-an-array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count specific values in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558397/count-specific-values-in-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a more object orientated way you can solve it as follows

```
$values = new ArrayObject();
$iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($info);
iterator_apply($iterator, 'countDistinct', array($iterator, $values));

function countDistinct($iterator, $values) {
    while ( $iterator -> valid() ) {
        if ( $iterator -> hasChildren() ) {
            countDistinct($iterator -> getChildren(), $values);
        } else {
            if (!$values->offsetExists($iterator->key())) {
                $values->offsetSet($iterator->key(), new ArrayObject());
            }

            if (!$values->offsetGet($iterator->key())->offsetExists($iterator->current())) {
                $values->offsetGet($iterator->key())
                    ->offsetSet($iterator->current(), 1);
            } else {
                $values->offsetGet($iterator->key())
                    ->offsetSet($iterator->current(),
                $values->offsetGet($iterator->key())->offsetGet($iterator->current()) + 1);
            }
        }

        $iterator -> next();
    }
}
```

Sure, with this example you do not avoid the loop. But with the ArrayObject and the RecursiveArrayIterator you will have some memory and performance advantages.

The result of this will exactly match your expected result, which you can easyliy iterate with the getIterator() function of the ArrayObject.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running PHP 5.5, you can use:

```
$newArray = array(
    'car' => array_count_values(array_column($info, 'car')),
    'previous_car' => array_count_values(array_column($info, 'previous_car'))
);
var_dump($newArray);
```

For versions of PHP prior to 5.5

```
$newArray = array(
    'car' => array_count_values(
        array_map(
            function($value) {
                return $value['car'];
            },
            $info
        )
    ),
    'previous_car' => array_count_values(
        array_map(
            function($value) {
                return $value['previous_car'];
            },
            $info
        )
    )
);
var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the server is running PHP 5.4.9

Comment: Dumping the $newArray gives only: `code` array(2) { ["car"]=> array(0) { } ["previous_car"]=> array(0) { } } `code`

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks¡

Answer (score 0):

Here is what might help you:

```
$returnArray = array('car' => NULL, 'previous_car' => NULL);

foreach($info as $newInfo) {
    $returnArray['car'][] = $newInfo['car'];
    $returnArray['previous_car'][] = $newInfo['previous_car'];
}

$ret['car'] = array_count_values($returnArray['car']);
$ret['previous_car'] = array_count_values($returnArray['previous_car']);

var_dump($ret);
```

This returns:

```
array (size=2)
  'car' => 
    array (size=3)
      'Audi' => int 3
      'BMW' => int 1
      'Ford' => int 1
  'previous_car' => 
    array (size=2)
      'BMW' => int 3
      'Seat' => int 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'd recommend any native functions for this task.  Using nested `foreach()` loops will probably be cleanest.  Use each row's key and value as the first and second level keys and increment tally with each occurrence.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GQHTE))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($info as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        $result[$k][$v] = ($result[$k][$v] ?? 0) + 1;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a function that will sort your data but for now check this out:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php