# Use array_count_values() and still keep key -- PHP

Tags: php

Let's say I have two arrays...

```
$radicand_array = array(3, 5, 5, 2);
$coeff_array = array(-10, 14, 3, -6);
```

I'd like to be able to determine which (if any) values in `$radicand_array` match, AND also know what the keys are.  So, in this case I would want to know that there's a match on keys 1 and 2 of `$radicand_array`.

I need to know this because I want to then add the corresponding key values in `$coeff_array`.  So, in this case I would then add 14 and 3 based on the matching 5's in `$radicand_array`.

I've tried `array_count_values()`, but it doesn't seem to give the key values like I want.  Is there a PHP function ready made for this?

Comment: Please, add desired output of given example data.

Comment: Here appears a promising answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460993/get-the-keys-for-duplicate-values-in-an-array

Comment: Can you tell me what you expect as finel result of this??

Comment: As explained in the post, I would expect the output to tell me that keys 1 and 2 match in `$radicand_array`.  If `$radicand_array` was `array(3, 5, 5, 2, 5)`, then I would expect the output to tell me that keys 1, 2, and 4 match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the link:

Fixed. Good man!

```
<?php
    // $radicand_array = array(3, 5, 5, 2);
    $radicand_array = array(3, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3);
    $coeff_array = array(-10, 14, 3, -6);

    $unique = array_unique($radicand_array);
    $duplicates = array_diff_assoc($radicand_array, $unique);

    // Duplicate keys
    $aDupes = array_keys(array_intersect($radicand_array, $duplicates));
    $iSum = 0;
    $iCountDupes = count( $aDupes );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountDupes; ++$i )
    {
        if( !empty( $coeff_array[ $aDupes[ $i ] ] ) )
        {
            $iSum = $iSum + $coeff_array[ $aDupes[ $i ] ];
        }
    }
    var_dump( $iSum );
?>
```

Comment: almost there, use those keys in the second array and get the sum

Comment: I just found an issue.  This seems to not work if `$radicand_array` were like this: `$radicand_array = array(3, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3);`.  In other words, if there are multiple matches.  Does that completely change things?

Comment: Fixed. Needs an empty check if the coeff array has less values.

Comment: I should have been more specific.  I'm assuming that $coeff_array has a matching number of values.  I believe I've got it though, so I'll be posting that as an answer in a moment.  Credit to Vladimir Ramik though.

Answer (score 0):

This is an edited version of Vladimir Ramik's post to handle multiple sets of matches...

```
$radicand_array = array(3, 5, 5, 2, 3);
$coeff_array = array(-10, 14, 3, -6, 4);

$unique = array_unique($radicand_array);
$duplicates = array_diff_assoc($radicand_array, $unique);

$new_array = array_chunk($duplicates, 1);
// Duplicate keys
$aDupes = array_keys(array_intersect($radicand_array, $new_array[0]));

$iCountDupes = count( $aDupes );
        for($i = 0; $i < $iCountDupes; ++$i){
            $ans_coeff_1 += $coeff_array[$aDupes[ $i ]];
        }

        echo $ans_coeff_1;

// Duplicate keys
$bDupes = array_keys(array_intersect($radicand_array, $new_array[1]));

$iCountDupes = count( $bDupes );
        for($i = 0; $i < $iCountDupes; ++$i){
            $ans_coeff_2 += $coeff_array[$bDupes[ $i ]];
        }

        echo '<br>' . $ans_coeff_2;
```