# Codeigniter : How to remove duplicate element from array specified by index name

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, duplicates

How to remove Duplicate Array element by specifying index like article_id
That means there would no other element having same article id in array .

This is what i am getting

```
$data["related_post"]   =$CI->Article_model->get_related_post($SearchTag);
```

and

```
echo "<pre>";
 print_r($data["related_post"]);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [article_id] => 49
            [article_viewed] => 156
            [article_title] => Copy 1 column to another by mysql query
            [article_url] => copy-1-column-to-another-by-mysql-query
            [article_status] => active
            [tag_name] => mysql
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [article_id] => 49
            [article_viewed] => 156
            [article_title] => Copy 1 column to another by mysql query
            [article_url] => copy-1-column-to-another-by-mysql-query
            [article_status] => active
            [tag_name] =>  sql
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [article_id] => 49
            [article_viewed] => 156
            [article_title] => Copy 1 column to another by mysql query
            [article_url] => copy-1-column-to-another-by-mysql-query
            [article_status] => active
            [tag_name] =>  unique-key
        )

)
```

Comment: Tip: `array_unique()` (maybe buggy on instances) or an simple `foreach` and create an new array where the index is the id.

Comment: Best way is you need to remove the duplicate records from the MYSQL query itself. You can use "DISTINCT" keyword for the article ID. So that you never get the duplicate records from DB. For ex SELECT DISTINCT(article_id) from table_name where keyword LIKE %copy%

Comment: JUST add `SELECT DISTINCT(`article_id`)...` in your query

Comment: Use `$this->group_by('article_id')`  or `$this->db->distinct();` or `$this->db->select('DISTINCT(article_id)');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_keys_for_duplicate_values($my_arr, $clean = false) {
    if ($clean) {
        return array_unique($my_arr);
    }

    $dups = $new_arr = array();
    foreach ($my_arr as $key => $val) {
      if (!isset($new_arr[$val])) {
         $new_arr[$val] = $key;
      } else {
        if (isset($dups[$val])) {
           $dups[$val][] = $key;
        } else {
           $dups[$val] = array($key);
           // Comment out the previous line, and uncomment the following line to
           // include the initial key in the dups array.
           // $dups[$val] = array($new_arr[$val], $key);
        }
      }
    }
    return $dups;
}
```

Source : 
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/6461034/7891160][1]