# Modification and replacement of nodes in xml file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

On daily basis, i receive an .xml file, but some additional editing of element values is required. I've done what i need in Excel via pivot tables, but that solution is not acceptable, since that creates new structure and i cant save it as xml, and i need same xml structure as output. Since i have PHP Composer installed, i think simpleXML library is the easyest solution. Raw .xml file is uploaded and modifications are done via simplexml_load_string function. Thing is, im not very profficient in that syntax, and i need some assistance. This is my .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
<ZCOLL>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
        <DOCNUM>0000000008857855</DOCNUM>
        <SERIAL>20191025143123</SERIAL>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <Z1COLL_AGENCY SEGMENT="1">
        <GPART>0000000101</GPART>
        <EMAIL>domain@domain.com</EMAIL>                        
        <Z1COLL_HEADER SEGMENT="1">
            <VKONT>200000541301</VKONT>
            <GPART>1000447089</GPART>
            <VKONA>22611402001</VKONA>
            <INKNO>00000000000101953558</INKNO>
            <INKBP>0000000101</INKBP>
            <INKDAT>20191025</INKDAT>
            <INKENDAT>20200123</INKENDAT>
            <BANKRUPTDAT>00000000</BANKRUPTDAT>
            <CLOSED/>
            <UPDATED_DATE>00000000</UPDATED_DATE>
            <COLLREFNR>200005413019-024-6</COLLREFNR>
            <NAME_ORG1>SOME OTHER NAME</NAME_ORG1>
            <LEG_CITY1>SOME OTHER CITY</LEG_CITY1>
            <LEG_POST_CODE1>105677</LEG_POST_CODE1>
            <LEG_STREET>ADDRESS 2</LEG_STREET>
            <LEG_HOUSE_NUM1/>
            <BU_SORT2>02226696981</BU_SORT2>
            <MAIL_CITY1>CITY 1</MAIL_CITY1>
            <MAIL_POST_CODE1>35220</MAIL_POST_CODE1>
            <MAIL_STREET>MAIL STREET 1</MAIL_STREET>
            <MAIL_HOUSE_NUM1/>
               <Z1COLL_ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                   <OPBEL>000210625857</OPBEL>
                   <XBLNR>0000198653579124</XBLNR>
                   <FAEDN>20190916</FAEDN>
                   <AGDAT>20191025</AGDAT>
                   <INITAMNT>         80.00</INITAMNT>
                   <PAYAMNT>          0.00</PAYAMNT>
                   <WRTOFFAMNT>          0.00</WRTOFFAMNT>
                   <OPENAMNT>         80.00</OPENAMNT>
                   <INVAMNT>         80.00</INVAMNT>
                   <WAERS>HRK</WAERS>
                   <RECINKDAT>00000000</RECINKDAT>
               </Z1COLL_ITEM>

               <Z1COLL_ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                   <OPBEL>000210625857</OPBEL>
                   <XBLNR>0000198653579124</XBLNR>
                   <FAEDN>20191016</FAEDN>
                   <AGDAT>20191025</AGDAT>
                   <INITAMNT>         80.00</INITAMNT>
                   <PAYAMNT>          0.00</PAYAMNT>
                   <WRTOFFAMNT>          0.00</WRTOFFAMNT>
                   <OPENAMNT>         80.00</OPENAMNT>
                   <INVAMNT>         80.00</INVAMNT>
                   <WAERS>HRK</WAERS>
                   <RECINKDAT>00000000</RECINKDAT>
               </Z1COLL_ITEM>

               <Z1COLL_ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                   <OPBEL>019183828875</OPBEL>
                   <XBLNR>2261140200119081</XBLNR>
                   <FAEDN>20190816</FAEDN>
                   <AGDAT>20191025</AGDAT>
                   <INITAMNT>        159.00</INITAMNT>
                   <PAYAMNT>          0.00</PAYAMNT>
                   <WRTOFFAMNT>          0.00</WRTOFFAMNT>
                   <OPENAMNT>        159.00</OPENAMNT>
                   <INVAMNT>        159.00</INVAMNT>
                   <WAERS>CURRENCY</WAERS>
                   <RECINKDAT>00000000</RECINKDAT>
               </Z1COLL_ITEM>

               <MSISDNS>
                   <MSISDN>381653490012</MSISDN>
               </MSISDNS>
               <MCD_DATA>
                   <MCD_MONTHS/>
                   <MCD_AMOUNT/>
               </MCD_DATA>
            <PHONE_NUM/>
        </Z1COLL_HEADER>            
     </Z1COLL_AGENCY>
  </IDOC>
</ZCOLL>
```

What i need is, if OPBEL and XBLNR element values are identical, delete that node and replace it with single duplicated value of OPBEL and XBLNR and with summarized values of INITAMNT, PAYAMNT, WRTOFFAMNT, OPENAMNT and INVAMNT, and return .xml file with same structure.

This is my code, im stuck half way:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($_FILES['file']['name']);
    //echo "</pre>";
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
        $get = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        $arr = simplexml_load_string($get);

    foreach ($arr->IDOC->Z1COLL_AGENCY->Z1COLL_HEADER as $element) {
        $delete_node = array();
        foreach($element->Z1COLL_ITEM as $item) {   
            $doubles_XBLNR = array_count_values($item->XBLNR);
            $doubles_OPBEL = array_count_values($item->OPBEL);
            $doubles_no_XBLNR = count($doubles_XBLNR);
            $doubles_no_OPBEL = count($doubles_OPBEL);
                if (($doubles_no_XBLNR > 2) && ($doubles_no_OPBEL > 2)){
                    $item->INITAMNT += $item->INITAMNT;
                    $item->PAYAMNT += $item->PAYAMNT;
                    $item->WRTOFFAMNT += $item->WRTOFFAMNT;
                    $$item->OPENAMNT += $item->OPENAMNT;
                    $item->INVAMNT += $item->INVAMNT;
                }                   
        }
        echo "<br />";  
    }
```

And this is desired xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
<ZCOLL>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
        <DOCNUM>0000000008857855</DOCNUM>
        <SERIAL>20191025143123</SERIAL>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <Z1COLL_AGENCY SEGMENT="1">
        <GPART>0000000101</GPART>
        <EMAIL>domain@domain.com</EMAIL>                    
        <Z1COLL_HEADER SEGMENT="1">
            <VKONT>200000541301</VKONT>
            <GPART>1000447089</GPART>
            <VKONA>22611402001</VKONA>
            <INKNO>00000000000101953558</INKNO>
            <INKBP>0000000101</INKBP>
            <INKDAT>20191025</INKDAT>
            <INKENDAT>20200123</INKENDAT>
            <BANKRUPTDAT>00000000</BANKRUPTDAT>
            <CLOSED/>
            <UPDATED_DATE>00000000</UPDATED_DATE>
            <COLLREFNR>200005413019-024-6</COLLREFNR>
            <NAME_ORG1>SOME OTHER NAME</NAME_ORG1>
            <LEG_CITY1>SOME OTHER CITY</LEG_CITY1>
            <LEG_POST_CODE1>105677</LEG_POST_CODE1>
            <LEG_STREET>ADDRESS 2</LEG_STREET>
            <LEG_HOUSE_NUM1/>
            <BU_SORT2>02226696981</BU_SORT2>
            <MAIL_CITY1>CITY 1</MAIL_CITY1>
            <MAIL_POST_CODE1>35220</MAIL_POST_CODE1>
            <MAIL_STREET>MAIL STREET 1</MAIL_STREET>
            <MAIL_HOUSE_NUM1/>
               <Z1COLL_ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                   <OPBEL>000210625857</OPBEL>
                   <XBLNR>0000198653579124</XBLNR>
                   <FAEDN>20190916</FAEDN>
                   <AGDAT>20191025</AGDAT>
                   <INITAMNT>         160.00</INITAMNT>
                   <PAYAMNT>          0.00</PAYAMNT>
                   <WRTOFFAMNT>          0.00</WRTOFFAMNT>
                   <OPENAMNT>         160.00</OPENAMNT>
                   <INVAMNT>         160.00</INVAMNT>
                   <WAERS>CURRENCY</WAERS>
                   <RECINKDAT>00000000</RECINKDAT>
               </Z1COLL_ITEM>

               <Z1COLL_ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                   <OPBEL>019183828875</OPBEL>
                   <XBLNR>2261140200119081</XBLNR>
                   <FAEDN>20190816</FAEDN>
                   <AGDAT>20191025</AGDAT>
                   <INITAMNT>        159.00</INITAMNT>
                   <PAYAMNT>          0.00</PAYAMNT>
                   <WRTOFFAMNT>          0.00</WRTOFFAMNT>
                   <OPENAMNT>        159.00</OPENAMNT>
                   <INVAMNT>        159.00</INVAMNT>
                   <WAERS>CURRENCY</WAERS>
                   <RECINKDAT>00000000</RECINKDAT>
               </Z1COLL_ITEM>
               <MSISDNS>
                   <MSISDN>381653490012</MSISDN>
               </MSISDNS>
               <MCD_DATA>
                   <MCD_MONTHS/>
                   <MCD_AMOUNT/>
               </MCD_DATA>
               <PHONE_NUM/>
         </Z1COLL_HEADER>           
    </Z1COLL_AGENCY>
  </IDOC>
 </ZCOLL>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document manipulations are much easier with DOM because each part is represented by a node object that knows about its context. For your case you can build up an index of nodes grouped by a key generated from the OPBEL and XBLNR values. Then merge the grouped nodes.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXML());
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

// iterate all header elements (do not merge items from different headers)
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//Z1COLL_HEADER ') as $header) {
    $groups = [];
    // iterate the items
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('Z1COLL_ITEM', $header) as $item) {
        // combine keys into a single string
        $groupKey = $xpath->evaluate('concat(OPBEL, "|", XBLNR)', $item);
        if (!isset($groups[$groupKey])) {
            $groups[$groupKey] = [];
        }
        // add the current item to a group defined by the generated key
        $groups[$groupKey][] = $item;
    } 
    // now filter for groups with multiple items
    $groups = array_filter($groups, function($group) { return count($group) > 1; });

    // iterate the groups with multiple items
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        // extract the first item node from the array
        $firstItem = array_shift($group);
        // iterate the other items of the group
        foreach ($group as $item) {
            $merges = ['INITAMNT', 'PAYAMNT', 'WRTOFFAMNT', 'OPENAMNT', 'INVAMNT'];
            // iterate the child node names to merge
            foreach ($merges as $merge) {
                // get the node of the first item
                $target = $xpath->evaluate($merge, $firstItem)->item(0);
                // get the node of the current item
                $source = $xpath->evaluate($merge, $item)->item(0);
                // if here are both
                if ($target && $source) {
                   // sum the values and format them 
                   $target->textContent = number_format(
                       $target->textContent + $source->textContent, 2
                   );
                } elseif ($source) {
                   // if the child does not exists in the first node move it over 
                   $firstItem->appendChild($source);    
                }
            }
            $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
        }
    }
}

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Comment: Interesting how much of a difference is in using DOMDocument and SimpleXML.

Comment: Different viewpoints: SimpleXML is an abstraction that is trying to map XML to class/object structures. It treats data as code. DOM itself is a tree of objects representing a data structure.

Comment: I was more talking about the differences between the API's, both use DOM with their own interpretation of how you can access the content.  I know DOMDocument is more powerful and more precise about how it allows this, but SimpleXML (IMHO) has it's place in pure data processing like this example.

Answer (score 0):

May the following code will answer your question.

You can use `dom` and `xpath` too in order to parse the `xml`. I would create a search array that contains the `OPBEL` and `XBLNR` values by their occurrence index.

Then you can find the duplicated node indices using [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), [array_diff_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php), [array_keys](https://www.php.net/array_keys) and [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6461117/3278362).

Now, you can remove the duplicated nodes and insert a new one with their aggregated values. Here is the code, where `data/input.xml` is your provided xml file.

```
$xml = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/data/input.xml');
$dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
@$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//Z1COLL_ITEM');

$search = [];
$index = 0;

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $OPBEL = $xpath->query('OPBEL', $node)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $XBLNR = $xpath->query('XBLNR', $node)->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $search[$index] = $OPBEL . $XBLNR;
    $index++;
}

// Unique values
$unique = array_unique($search);

// Duplicates
$duplicates = array_diff_assoc($search, $unique);

// Get duplicate keys
$duplicateIndeces = array_keys(array_intersect($search, $duplicates));

$aggregate = [];

$firstNode = $xpath->query('//Z1COLL_ITEM')->item($duplicateIndeces[0]);

// Iterate through the duplicated nodes
foreach (array_slice($duplicateIndeces, 1) as $duplicateIndex) {
    $node = $xpath->query('//Z1COLL_ITEM')->item($duplicateIndex);

    // Update the desired values for the first occurrence
    $xpath->query('INITAMNT', $firstNode)->item(0)->nodeValue += $xpath->query('INITAMNT', $node)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $xpath->query('PAYAMNT', $firstNode)->item(0)->nodeValue += $xpath->query('PAYAMNT', $node)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $xpath->query('WRTOFFAMNT', $firstNode)->item(0)->nodeValue += $xpath->query('WRTOFFAMNT', $node)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $xpath->query('OPENAMNT', $firstNode)->item(0)->nodeValue += $xpath->query('OPENAMNT', $node)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $xpath->query('INVAMNT', $firstNode)->item(0)->nodeValue += $xpath->query('INVAMNT', $node)->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // Remove the duplicated node
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

The generated output is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
<ZCOLL>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
        <DOCNUM>0000000008857855</DOCNUM>
        <SERIAL>20191025143123</SERIAL>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <Z1COLL_AGENCY SEGMENT="1">
        <GPART>0000000101</GPART>
        <EMAIL>domain@domain.com</EMAIL>                        
        <Z1COLL_HEADER SEGMENT="1">
            <VKONT>200000541301</VKONT>
            <GPART>1000447089</GPART>
            <VKONA>22611402001</VKONA>
            <INKNO>00000000000101953558</INKNO>
            <INKBP>0000000101</INKBP>
            <INKDAT>20191025</INKDAT>
            <INKENDAT>20200123</INKENDAT>
            <BANKRUPTDAT>00000000</BANKRUPTDAT>
            <CLOSED/>
            <UPDATED_DATE>00000000</UPDATED_DATE>
            <COLLREFNR>200005413019-024-6</COLLREFNR>
            <NAME_ORG1>SOME OTHER NAME</NAME_ORG1>
            <LEG_CITY1>SOME OTHER CITY</LEG_CITY1>
            <LEG_POST_CODE1>105677</LEG_POST_CODE1>
            <LEG_STREET>ADDRESS 2</LEG_STREET>
            <LEG_HOUSE_NUM1/>
            <BU_SORT2>02226696981</BU_SORT2>
            <MAIL_CITY1>CITY 1</MAIL_CITY1>
            <MAIL_POST_CODE1>35220</MAIL_POST_CODE1>
            <MAIL_STREET>MAIL STREET 1</MAIL_STREET>
            <MAIL_HOUSE_NUM1/>
               <Z1COLL_ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                   <OPBEL>000210625857</OPBEL>
                   <XBLNR>0000198653579124</XBLNR>
                   <FAEDN>20190916</FAEDN>
                   <AGDAT>20191025</AGDAT>
                   <INITAMNT>160</INITAMNT>
                   <PAYAMNT>0</PAYAMNT>
                   <WRTOFFAMNT>0</WRTOFFAMNT>
                   <OPENAMNT>160</OPENAMNT>
                   <INVAMNT>160</INVAMNT>
                   <WAERS>HRK</WAERS>
                   <RECINKDAT>00000000</RECINKDAT>
               </Z1COLL_ITEM>



               <Z1COLL_ITEM SEGMENT="1">
                   <OPBEL>019183828875</OPBEL>
                   <XBLNR>2261140200119081</XBLNR>
                   <FAEDN>20190816</FAEDN>
                   <AGDAT>20191025</AGDAT>
                   <INITAMNT>        159.00</INITAMNT>
                   <PAYAMNT>          0.00</PAYAMNT>
                   <WRTOFFAMNT>          0.00</WRTOFFAMNT>
                   <OPENAMNT>        159.00</OPENAMNT>
                   <INVAMNT>        159.00</INVAMNT>
                   <WAERS>CURRENCY</WAERS>
                   <RECINKDAT>00000000</RECINKDAT>
               </Z1COLL_ITEM>

               <MSISDNS>
                   <MSISDN>381653490012</MSISDN>
               </MSISDNS>
               <MCD_DATA>
                   <MCD_MONTHS/>
                   <MCD_AMOUNT/>
               </MCD_DATA>
            <PHONE_NUM/>
        </Z1COLL_HEADER>            
     </Z1COLL_AGENCY>
  </IDOC>
</ZCOLL>
```

Comment: Hmm, no errors, but no echoed values, var_dump gives string(39) " "

Comment: Ok, solved, that was my mistake by editing some parts, now i cant get rid of " Uncaught Error: Call to a member function removeChild()"

Comment: @Greedy For me the result is fine using your input xml. What are the output of the vairables `$search`, `$nodes`, `$duplicateIndeces`, `$firstNode`?

Comment: Ok, ive figure it out, code works as intended. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend XSLT for this. It looks to me like (in XSLT 3.0):

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  expand-text="yes">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="Z1COLL_HEADER">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* except Z1COLL_ITEM"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Z1COLL_ITEM" group-by="OPBEL, XBLNR" composite="yes">
       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]/(OPBEL,XBLNR, FAEDN, AGDAT)"/>
       <INITAMNT>{sum(current-group()/INITAMT)}</INITAMNT>
       <PAYAMNT>{sum(current-group()/PAYAMNT)}</PAYAMNT>
       <WRTOFFAMNT>{sum(current-group()/WRTOFFAMNT)}</WRTOFFAMNT>
       <OPENAMNT>{sum(current-group()/OPENAMNT)}</OPENAMNT>
       <INVAMNT>{sum(current-group()/INVAMNT)}</INVAMNT>
       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]/(WAERS, RECINKDAT)"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Solutions with earlier XSLT versions are also possible but a bit more wordy.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses SimpleXML and basically keeps a track of the elements it has so far found and then if it finds another similar record, just adds the values to the first one found.  It then uses (in this case) `unset($entry[0]);` to remove the duplicate entry from the original document...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$existing = [];

foreach ( $xml->xpath("//Z1COLL_ITEM") as $entry )  {
    $index = $entry->OPBEL."#".$entry->XBLNR;
    if ( isset ($existing[$index]) )    {
        $existing[$index]->INITAMNT += $entry->INITAMNT;
        $existing[$index]->PAYAMNT += $entry->PAYAMNT;
        $existing[$index]->WRTOFFAMNT += $entry->WRTOFFAMNT;
        $existing[$index]->OPENAMNT += $entry->OPENAMNT;
        $existing[$index]->INVAMNT += $entry->INVAMNT;
        unset($entry[0]);
    }
    else {
        $existing[$index] = $entry;
    }
}
```